# YAML Exception: missed comma between flow collection entries

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm facing a YAML parsing error, and the YAML is from a Helm chart.

YAML input

```
   - name: es-cm-update
     {{- with .Values.kubelet.extraEnvFrom }}
     envFrom: {{ toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
     {{- end }}
     image: "{{ .Values.images.k8sawscli.repository }}"
     imagePullPolicy: "Always"        
     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
     args: ["echo ${es_password}"]
```

JSON Output error

Error: YAMLException: missed comma between flow collection entries at line 2, column 12:
{{- with .Values.kubelet.extraEnvF ...
^

Any thoughts on what could be causing the error?. Thanks

Comment: To double-check, how are you using this YAML file?  Helm runs the Go `text/template` engine over the file before sending it to the cluster; the `{{- with }}...{{- end }}` markup is not standard YAML syntax.